# Why does the insert function produce this result?

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_list = [1, 2]

for v in range(2):
    my_list.insert(-1, my_list[v])
    
print(my_list)
```

The Result specifies 1, 1, 1, 2. Why isn't the result 1, 1, 2, 2 since v in the for loop would be 0 = 1 and 1 = 2?

Comment: The second insert happens after you have already inserted an element into the list, shifting the 2 to a later index. Try printing the state of the list on each iteration and this will be clear. See also [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=my_list%20%3D%20%5B1,%202%5D%0A%0Afor%20v%20in%20range%282%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20my_list.insert%28-1,%20my_list%5Bv%5D%29%0A%20%20%20%20%0Aprint%28my_list%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Answer (score 0):

`list.insert(index, val)` determines the index of the element before which to insert.
So in your first iteration you insert a value between the 1 and the 2.
Your new list looks like `[1,1,2]`.
In the next iteration you operate on the changed list, thus you use the newly inserted 1, which is at `v=1` now. Thus your list looks like

```
[1,1,1,2]
 ^ 1 2 ^
```

Here ^ are the original values and 1 and 2 are the iterations the values are added.